# Why does 'DNSServiceRegisterRecord' not return reference, if there are many ip addresses on the adapter?

Tags: dns, bonjour, mdns, zeroconf, dns-sd

I am registering about 80 ip addresses on my router, creating udp sockets, and want to do Bonjour registration for each ip. But the registrations are extremely slow, or failing in presence of so many ips.Registrations are successful when there are upto 40 ips.
I am using pybonjour library, and OS is windows10.

The problem seems to be in the pybonjour methods 'DNSServiceCreateConnection', 'DNSServiceRegisterRecord' and 'DNSServiceRegister'(executed in the same order for bonjour registrations). They are very slow in returning reference when so many ips have been registered on the adapter.

No error messages are coming, but they are not completing either. What could be the solution?